# How to initialize variables inside subclasses' initializer that will be used in the super class's initializer?

Tags: swift

In the following code, my intention is to have `repeatNum` declared in the base class because it is used in the base class (inside `init` and other functions). And each subclass should set `repeatNum` because only the subclass knows its own value.

```
class Base {
    var repeatNum: Int

    init() {
       for var i=0; i<repeatNum; ++i {
           print("*")
       }
    }
}

class SubClass1 : Base {
    override init() {
        repeatNum = 10
        super.init()
    }
}

class SubClass2 : Base {
    override init() {
        repeatNum = 5
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Of course, it prompts some errors:

For the base class:

> 'self.repeatNum' not initialized
>
> Return from initializer without initiating all stored properties.

For the subclasses:

> use of 'self' in property access 'repeatNum' before super.init initializes self

I know I can simply call `super.init()` before setting `repeatNum` in the subclasses, but I really need to use `repeatNum` inside the base's `init()` in the real case. It becomes a paradox for me here somehow.

I also understand I can change the design to make the errors go away, but I am wondering if it's possible to achieve my original intention with some tweaks? I probably miss something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code doesn't even compile, does it? It should complain about trying to use `repeatNum` before being initialized...

Maybe something like this could be an option for you?

```
class Base {
  var repeatNum: Int

  init(repeatNum: Int) {
    self.repeatNum = repeatNum

    for _ in 0..<repeatNum {
      print("*")
    }
  }
}

class SubClass1 : Base {
  init() {
    super.init(repeatNum: 10)
  }
}

class SubClass2 : Base {
  init() {
    super.init(repeatNum: 5)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. What if the `Base` class inherits `UITableViewCell`? In this case, it seems I cannot change `init` parameters? If this is a different question, I will try to look into this, but if you have some quick answer or direction, just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: How about adding a custom convenience initializer via a class extension and then override that in your subclasses?

Comment: I still can't figure out how to do it. I asked a separate question for this, would you please provide some further help? Thanks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174714/how-to-pass-value-to-superclasss-init-bypassing-the-designated-initalizer-that

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is you want,the following code is that ok

```
class Base {
    var repeatNum: Int?

    init() {

    }

    func printyourneed(){
        for var i=0; i<repeatNum; ++i {
            print("*")
        }
    }
}

class SubClass1 : Base {
    override init() {
         super.init()
        self.repeatNum = 10
       self.printyourneed()
    }
}

class SubClass2 : Base {
    override init() {
         super.init()
        self.repeatNum = 5
       self.printyourneed()
    }
}
```

or

```
class Base {
    var _repeatNum:Int?;
    var repeatNum: Int?{
        get{
            return _repeatNum
        }
        set{
            _repeatNum =  newValue
            printyourneed()
        }
    }

    init() {

    }

    func printyourneed(){
        for var i=0; i<repeatNum; ++i {
            print("*")
        }
    }
}

class SubClass1 : Base {
    override init() {
         super.init()
        self.repeatNum = 10

    }
}

class SubClass2 : Base {
    override init() {
         super.init()
        self.repeatNum = 5

    }
}
```