# How to pass value to superclass's init bypassing the designated initalizer that is required by its superclass?

Tags: swift

I have a base class that inherits `UITableViewCell` that declares a variable to store type value which will be used in `init` and other functions:

```
class CellBase: UITableViewCell {
    var type: Int
    init(theType: Int) {
        type = theType
        if (type == 100) {  // more init code based on 'type'
        } else {  
        }
    } 
    // other functions
}
```

And I have subclasses that inherits `CellBase`:

```
class Cell1: CellBase {
    init() {
        super.init(type: 100)
    }
}
class Cell2: CellBase {
    init() {
        super.init(type: 200)
    }
}
```

I want to pass the value of `type` to `CellBase`. However I cannot figure out a way to do so. XCode shows some error:

> 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewCell'

If I modify the code to override the required initalizer:

```
class CellBase2 : UITableViewCell {
    var type: Int

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I am unable to pass the type value to `CellBase` from the subclasses. How to solve this?

Comment: how would you supply the type if the cell is unpacked from a NIB? can you? hence the `fatal error`...

Comment: @Wain I am not using NIB. All views are created programatically. And my problem is not about the `fatalError`. Thanks.

Comment: the point is you already have code which resolves your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vadian beat me to it, but since I already coded this up, here's an alternative with two different custom initializers in the subclasses, and making use of a lazy variable for `type` in the superclass. The lazy var isn't really needed here, per se, but to avoid having to initialize `type` also in the `aDecoder` init (unless you use `fatalError` there), you could make sure all non-lazy/non-computed properties in `CellBase` are initialized with default values.

Superclass:

```
class CellBase: UITableViewCell {
    var defaultType = 100
    lazy var type: Int = { return self.defaultType }()

    init(reuseIdentifier: String?, theType: Int) {
        defaultType = theType

        super.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if (type == 100) {  // more init code based on 'type'
            print("Intialized Cell1")
        }
        else {
            print("Intialized Cell2")
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Subclasses:

```
/* Style: .Default */
class Cell1: CellBase {

    /* Allow for caller to specify reuse identifier */
    init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, theType: 100)
    }

    /* No reuse identifier (nil) */
    init() {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: nil, theType: 100)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class Cell2: CellBase {
    init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, theType: 200)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: nil, theType: 200)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let c1A = Cell1(reuseIdentifier: "SomeCell1")   // "Intialized Cell1"
let c1B = Cell1()                               // "Intialized Cell1"
let c2A = Cell2(reuseIdentifier: "SomeCell2")   // "Intialized Cell2"
let c2B = Cell2()                               // "Intialized Cell2"
```

Comment: The cell is eventually used by `registerClass` and  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. I am wondering if any modification/tweak is needed?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to call `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)` declare a custom `init` method including your parameter and call the designated initializer

```
class CellBase: UITableViewCell {
  var type: Int

  init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?, type: Int) {
    self.type = type
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  // other functions
}

class Cell1: CellBase {

  init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, type: 100)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}

let cell = Cell1(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")
cell.type // 100
```

Comment: Is it possible to make `(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1", type: 100)` inside Cell1 class instead? And is it possible not to specify `.Default` and `"cell1"`? (since the cell is used eventually by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am still confused with one thing. Since the cell is eventually used by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.. I never specify the `style: .Default` and `resueIndentifier: "cell1"` before, is it possible not to specify them?

Comment: If the cell is designed in Interface Builder, the initializer is called with the appropriate settings.

Comment: the cell is not designed in IB. no IB is used in my app.

Comment: You can call the designated initializer in super passing custom default parameters like dfri partially does in his answer.